# Detect a point of infrared light using an Android smartphone

Tags: android, infrared

I was wondering if anyone here has any pointers on how I might go about doing IR point recognition using an Android smartphone without modifying the hardware. It can be a (steady) single point.

I know that the camera I have (galaxy nexus) can see the IR source fairly well, but I don't know how to /if it's something that I can filter the returning image for.

Can anyone tell me if there are any open source / commercial projects out there to do this? If not, how would I get started trying to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to the best of my knowledge, the IR light captured by the sensor is indistinguishable from a visible light source when presented in the image, after all it is simply RGB at that point.

In order to detect the presence of an IR source you would be best to exclude the visible light using photographic filters. In theory this can be done cheaply and non destructively using colour film negatives placed over the lens of the camera, but I have not tried. Once you have excluded the visible light detecting a point source is a case of processing the image for a suitably intense spot.